# How to require module only if exist. React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, metro-bundler

Example:

```
let tmp;

try {
  tmp = require('module-name');
} catch(e) {
  return;
}
```

I get error (react native Metro Bundler):

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `module-name` from ...
```

How to require "module-name" only if exist?

Comment: Try `require.resolve(PACKAGE_NAME)`

Comment: @PritishVaidya not working(( Same error

Answer (score 3):

That's what works for me:

```
let myPackage;
const myPackageToRequire = 'my-package-to-require';
try {
  myPackage = require.call(null, myPackageToRequire);
} catch (e) {}
```

The variable definition `const myPackageToRequire = 'my-package-to-require';` is necessary here.

Hope I helped.

Comment: When I am testing this with a module I absolutely have in my node_modules (inappbrowser-reborn), I am getting: Unknown named module: "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn".

Answer (score 0):

Loading optional dependencies via try-catch has been [added in Metro 0.59](https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/e54819c4defb418949ecb26fa16d3fea187e497a), which in turn means that you should be able to use your original code in React Native 0.63 if you turn it on in `metro.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    allowOptionalDependencies: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Hello @Petr Bela, I need to use optional dependencies. I already did this but still nothing changes. Can you explain this to me a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) which will return resolved file name.

```
function checkModuleAvailability (module) {
  try {
    require.resolve(module);
    return true
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(`${module} not found`);
  }
  return false
}

const moduleAvailable = checkModuleAvailability(MODULE_NAME) // true or false
```

Comment: It doesn't work for Metro Bundler. You'll possibly have `[TypeError: _$$_REQUIRE.resolve is not a function. (In '_$$_REQUIRE.resolve('package-name')', '_$$_REQUIRE.resolve' is undefined)]`