# Optional require in JS React Native / Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, require

### Problem

I want to add an optional configuration file to my expo app.

### What I've tried

I tried to include the file like this:

```
const url = require('./config.json').url
```

This works if the file exists, but it has to also work when it doesn't exist. If I now delete the file, I can't compile my application since `require` resolves before runtime. Surrounding it with try-catch doesn't work either.

I also tried [optional-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optional-require) and [require-optional](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-optional) from npm, but both require libraries not available in a react native app.

### Goal

I would prefer to avoid filesystem checks and resolve it statically, but it needs to gracefully abort if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you use this config for? If this is part of your app, there are other ways (check storage at documentation) to check if file exists. If it's included in developement phase you need pre-build script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to require module only if exist. React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722700/how-to-require-module-only-if-exist-react-native)

Answer (score -1):

Include a `config_example.json` file in your repo. Copy it to `config.json` at startup.